# Group by and order By together are causing error

Tags: sql

I have sql query where I am using group by and order By but it is giving error not a GROUP BY expression

```
select co.id , count(col.course_fk) from student co inner join 
course col on col.course_fk = co."ID" where (co.phone=:param)
group by co.id  ORDER BY co.create_date_time asc;
```

If I remove orderBy then it is running fine and giving result.  How should I change my query so that I can use both order by and group by.

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

The `order by` column is not in the `select`.  So, use an aggregation column.  I might guess:

```
select co.id, count(col.course_fk)
from student co inner join 
     course col
    on col.course_fk = co.ID
where co.phone = :param
group by co.id  
order by min(co.create_date_time) asc;
```

Or include the column in the `group by`:

```
select co.id, count(col.course_fk)
from student co inner join 
     course col
    on col.course_fk = co.ID
where co.phone = :param
group by co.id, co.create_date_time
order by co.create_date_time asc;
```

Note:  Your original version would not cause a problem in MySQL if `course.id` is defined as the primary key.